# how can i retrieve data from django database in a json file in my local machine

Tags: json, django

I have created a school management website for a school nearby my house and I used django as backend for my website. I have the details of a student in my database..
I want all the data stored in django database to show me in a json file in my local machine

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=225)
   class_of_joining = models.CharField(max_length=225)
   adhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   current_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
   permanent_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
   blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=225)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [**`dumpdata`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) to dump data into a JSON blob. You can run this with:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata app_label.Student -o some_file.json
```